# Popular style sheet resources for widgets - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qlistwidget

Are there any online resources for popular style sheets for Widgets that would help change the look of widgets. I am interested in styles for QButtons, QTableView, and QListWidget.

Comment: Possible duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8813759/331041